# How to load environment variables in a remote AIX machine through ssh while running script from Jenkin pipeline?

Tags: perl, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, aix, jenkins-groovy

We are using some custom modules in our Perl automation framework which runs through Jenkin pipeline. Recently we got package not found error for all custom modules while executing test cases in  AIX servers as latest Perl version is installed there . So we tried to add "PERL5LIB" in the path as mentioned in document

https://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations

We added "export PERL5LIB=/home/foobar/code" in /etc/profile of the AIX server and script getting executed without any issue when running from local AIX machine.

Issue:

But we have Jenkin pipeline to execute the scripts in AIX server using ssh. Now when we do SSH to the AIX server in the pipeline script the variables that we have set in /etc/profile does not load and we get package not found error.

Question: How can I load the profile in the AIX server while running it from pipeline? or is there any other way to handle this. Before executing script I want to export PERL5LIB in remote AIX server through pipeline (only once) and the I should not get package not found error.

Below solutions I have tried :

Load the /etc/profile:  ssh AIX server  ./etc/profile  (using dot since source not working in AIX)

Adding this line "export PERL5LIB=/home/foobar/code" in .ssh/environment in AIX server and set PermitUserEnviorment yes

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Is this a module being installed alongside the script? If so, PERL5LIB is not the best solution anyway. `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealLib;` (or use lib "$RealLib/../lib";` or whatever is appropriate) in the script would make more sense, and avoid your problem entirely.

Comment: Hi @ikegami. Thanks for reply. We have tried using FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealLib; It works well but the problem is we have 400-500 perl files which use these modules. So thought PERL5LIB will be a simple solution.

Comment: If only there was a programming language that could used to easily add a line near the start of a text file... (`find . -name '*.pl' -exec perl -pe's/^(?=use strict)/use lib qw( \$RealBin );\n/' -i~ {} +`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved with below changes.

Step 1: Edit  ~/.ssh/environment. Add variable PERL5LIB="/path of the module/"

Step 2: Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Change variable PermitUserEnvironment from no to yes. Uncomment it if commented. This will enable access of environment variables to SSH.

Step 3: Restart SSHD service. (This is imp. I had tried step 1 and 2 before also but not restarted the service so solution was not working)

We can create a script and run it before executing automation test from pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Assign values to variables the usual way:

```
ssh user@host 'export PERL5LIB=/somepath; echo $PERL5LIB'
user@hosts's password:
/somepath
```

or

```
ssh user@host '. /etc/profile.local; echo $PERL5LIB'
user@hosts's password:
/somepath/from/profile
```

Edit:
    If you have to execute multiple commands, create a script and upload it to the target computer, for example:

```
SCRIPTNAME=/tmp/$$.$RANDOM.script
scp myscript.sh user@host:"$SCRIPTNAME"
ssh user@host "$SCRIPTNAME"
```

Comment: Hello @Lorinczy Zsigmond. Thanks for reply. Appreciate.  This solution also works but we need to add this in each and every ssh command . In our pipeline script  we execute some 20-30 Perl files in remote AIX server connecting through ssh.  Is there any way we export PERL5LIB only once at the beginning of the script and it should persist through out the  execution?